# How to debug a SQL Server table insertion that hangs?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

On my SQL Server, I have a query which does not produce any rows and this select statement runs for about a minute. Now I don't understand why the insert would not finish forever. The destination table has only 48k rows. I don't have rights to run any kinds of tracing or any other diagnostic queries that can help this. What else can I try?

Comment: insert or select?

Comment: Maybe take a data dump and populate a database on your own device where you control the rights.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you're having trouble with insert, why mention that SELECT takes a minute? You say destination table has 48k rows, but how many rows are you inserting? Is this a 100% reproducible problem? Is the problem application specific reproducible via SSMS? The are many possible causes of your problem but you need to narrow your question down and make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your insert into a select so you can see what you're trying to insert.  Then take parts away from your SQL statement (joins, sub queries, etc.) until it starts running quickly.  The last thing you removed was the cause of the slowness.